# Basic understanding of code, trying to write a code that changes range every 4 cells but not until the fourth cell

Tags: excel, vba, range, formula

I am trying to write a code that will change the range every so many cells, but not with each cell.

I have been able to do this using excel formulas specifically offset, but I cannot reproduce this within VBA

Comment: What's your code? You can use `Offset` or `Step` to do this.

Comment: If using offset in VBA can you specify range size, as you can in the formula section of Excel? I was under the impression that the optional variables found there were not able to be used in VBA to specify range size.

Comment: See the [`Range.Offset`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.offset) documentation.